# Incorrect request google books API

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api

I'm trying to get books from `google books API`, but I can't figure out the correctness of the request. I send

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers&key=<my key>
```

and in return comes to me

```
{ 
    "kind": "books#volumes", 
    "totalItems": 0 
}
```

And this comes to me in response to any request.

Comment: Can you please show some code snippet how are you making call to that API

Comment: For testing, I use postman

Comment: Ok, I tested on Google API console, it did worked for me though.

Comment: What answer is coming?

Comment: I am getting list of books and proper count.

Comment: Can you show your request?

Comment: I am calling from console like this 
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

and I am getting `"totalItems": 2639` as response.

Comment: console - 0 result, postman 0 result

Comment: Are you able to access this page https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/books/v1/books.volumes.list
Then try the API request from there.

Comment: Yes. 
200
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 0
}

Comment: That's odd, I am getting proper results. I am not sure maybe it has to do something with region where you are calling the API.

Comment: Perhaps you `re right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was in google system. Now everything is working correctly.